# How make an outgoing call from my app?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2

i develop a calling program in the below way.
my main aim is enter the number in textfield and whenever i press the call button it convert

into the integer and then perform calling action.in xcode is there any possibility to create a

code for outgoing call?

And is there any possibility to block the incoming calls?

i am writing the code below way.

my .h file is

```
@interface mytextViewController : UIViewController
{             
  IBOutlet UILabel *enterphonenumber;           
    int currentNumber;        
}

@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UILabel *enterphonenumber;

-(IBAction)call;

-(IBAction)press:(id)sender;

@end
```

my .m file is

```
-(IBAction)press:(id)sender    
{    
    currentNumber = currentNumber*10 + (int)[sender tag];

    enterphonenumber.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",currentNumber];    
}    

-(IBAction)call

{        
    int x =[enterphonenumber.text intValue];       

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:x]];
//[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"%tel:9963610177"]];
    NSLog(@"sample %@",[NSURL URLWithString:@"my phone number is calling"]);
}
```

And also how to examine it performs a calling

please any one help because i am the new to develop this application

Thanking you,

Comment: How to make a call and how to block incoming calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the **tel** protocol.

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPhone"])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%d", number]]];
}
```

You cannot block any incoming calls.

Answer (score 2):

You can't block any incoming calls in your app.