# How to do audio call in our application in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have one query like how to do audio call functionality device to device like same as whats app call and other application.

i have refereed quickblox and twillo documentation.can any one have steps for which i need to follow.

Any one can help me thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

(I am not able to comment due to low reputation)

Could you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9955087/1474080?

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] isEqualToString:@"iPhone"])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%d", number]]];
}
```

Or have you seen this documentation yet - Using this CallKit under the section, Making Outgoing Calls. ? 
https://developer.apple.com/reference/callkit

Comment: wow.. downvoted just like that. Do enlighten me if whatsapp did not develop using CallKit offered by Apple!